# Как изменить положение текста

Tags: php, javascript, css

Как изменить положение текста с тегом ?

```
html
<div class="footer">
 <i>by Misha Nikolov</i>
 <i>(C) Tunika7 2018</i>
</div>
```

Это не работает:

```
.footer i{
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сделать выравнивание в теге `i`, что не получится сделать без `display` и `width`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.footer i:first-child {
    float:left;
}
.footer i:last-child {
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
 <i>by Misha Nikolov</i>
 <i>(C) Tunika7 2018</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.footer {
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
 <i>by Misha Nikolov</i>
 <i>(C) Tunika7 2018</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется или этот вопрос дублируется?

```
<div class="footer">
 <div id="one">by Misha Nikolov</div>
 <div id="two">(C) Tunika7 2018</div>
</div>

#one {
  float: left;
}
#two {
  float: right;
}
```